# How to skip Ivy publish without causing error?

Tags: ivy

I would like to skip publishing an artifact if it already exists in the repository, but as far as I can see from the documentation there isn't a way to do this.  There is an `overwrite` attribute, but if set to false that causes the publish to fail if the artifact exists.  I definitely don't want to overwrite the artifact, either.

I've looked into using `<ivy:info>` and `<ivy:findrevision>` to see if the artifact exists and set a property I can use on my publish target (as an `unless` attribute, for example), but neither of these tasks allows me to specify the repository to check.

I'd rather not resort to using an external taskdef, like antcontrib's try/catch tasks.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Just an idea if you want to go the REST API route and you are using Artifactory Pro. You can use GET /api/search/versions?[g=groupId][&a=artifactId][&v=version][&remote=0/1][&repos=x[,y]] in your build.xml to check on that version first. Search for "Artifact Version Search" in https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF4X/Artifactory+REST+API for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Info and findrevision allow the settingsRef-attribute. So you could use an extra settings-file that only references the resolver you need (via ivy:settings and ivy:configure) and use that settingsRef in your task.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you run the "publish" task if you don't intend saving what you built?

I use the [buildnumber](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/buildnumber.html) task to ensure that my version number is incremented automatically based on what was previously published.

Comment: That's a fair question.  Let me rephrase: is there a way to avoid publishing if the version already exists in the repository?  I'm thinking of how to handle a top-level "publish" Ant target that publishes all of the child projects, but I only want to publish those with a changed version number.