# Ivy: Publish only if artifact does not yet exist in repository

Tags: ant, ivy

I want ivy:publish to do nothing if an an artifact already exists in Nexus.

I get java.io.IOException: destination file exists and overwrite == false
if I run the build with publish a second time, and I do not want to overwrite.

How can I run the build without Ivy trying to publish a second time?

I think this is similar to 
[How to skip Ivy publish without causing error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234059/how-to-skip-ivy-publish-without-causing-error)

Answer (score 0):

and 
as given in 
[How to skip Ivy publish without causing error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234059/how-to-skip-ivy-publish-without-causing-error)

worked for me, combined with condition and unless.